# Is it possible to use LWC with public access?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

We built wizard using LWC. Is it possible to publish wizard like visualforce on public page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, starting summer 19 , you can put LWC in VF page and then put that VF page in Force.com site.

Src: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_lwc_vf.htm

Comment: got this error when put visualforce to the public site

Comment: GET http://av-developer-edition.ap4.force.com/mainpage/c/clearapp.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT 404 (Not Found)

requestApp @ lightning.out.delegate.js?v=1559724170767:126

use @ lightning.out.delegate.js?v=1559724170767:140

script.onload @ lightning.out.js?v=2:46

load (async)

loadDelegateScript @ lightning.out.js?v=2:43

(anonymous) @ lightning.out.js?v=2:53

(anonymous) @ lightning.out.js?v=2:78

Comment: are you on summer 19?

Comment: you are right! It was winter'19. I tested on new sandbox and it works.